# Retrieving information about all users in a group

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How would I go about retrieving all the information about the users in the same group in a single query object? This is in order to populate some list ui where the users are displayed. I am using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter and in its constructor it requires a single query object. My data is structured in the same way as on the "Structure Your Database" page on the firebase docs.

In my particular case I am trying to obtain all the stories that have been bookmarked by a single user in one query object. The structure of my data is shown below:

[Stories structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WO2sS.png)

[Users structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAq7A.png)

I have attempted to do this:

```
Query recentPostsQuery = databaseReference.child("users/" + uid + "/bookmarks");
    recentPostsQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot storySnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                databaseReference.child("stories/" + storySnapshot.getKey());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    });
```

However, it doesn't work and I'm not too sure why.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: When I switch to the fragment that has this list displayed it just crashes the app..

Comment: please post the crash log

Comment: I've checked the logs and there seems to be a conversion error.. I'm assuming this is from the second query where I am attempting to look for the actual story objects but am still left with the boolean value from the bookmarks node in the user object

Comment: Sorry if I'm not formatting my responses correctly..

4823-4823/com.pbgt.story E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.pbgt.story, PID: 4823
                                                              com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.Boolean to type com.pbgt.story.model.Story

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a list to store stories and Model class Stories.

```
Query recentPostsQuery = databaseReference.child("users/" + uid + "/bookmarks");
recentPostsQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot storySnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            databaseReference.child("stories/" + storySnapshot.getKey()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListner(){
               @Override
               public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                //Stories your model class
                   for (DataSnapshot story : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                   Stories story = story.getValue(Stories.class);
                   //add story to list for showing in recycler view
                   // also call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                   }
               }
               @Override
               public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
             });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
});
```

I guess this helps..

Comment: Hi thank you for your response. Yes this is what I had for the previous way I had this query implemented in my code. However, I'm using the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter and it seems to be a little different as it supposedly handles the list of stories and the notifying without me doing anything..

Comment: in that case i will recommend you to choose custom adapter so you will have the control on the data that is shown. Its not that difficult